# How do I make C++ friend template specializations work?

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, specialization

I have a class that overloads the bit shift operator like the following:

```
    template<typename DataType>
    friend Packet& operator << (Packet& pkt, const DataType& data)
    {
          std::cout << "this compiles" << std::endl;
    }
```

but when I try to make a specialization of it like this :

```
    template<typename DataType>
    friend Packet& operator << (Packet& pkt, const DataType& data)
    {
          std::cout << "this doesn't compile" << std::endl;
    }

    template<>
    friend Packet& operator<<<std::string> (Packet& pkt, const std::string& data)
    {
          std::cout << "this doesn't compile" << std::endl;
    }
```

it throws a compile time error:

```
Error   C2116   'operator <<': function parameter lists do not match between declarations
```

what I'm I doing wrong here ?

Comment: Wouldn't a regular non-template overload work there? An actual [mcve] demonstrating the full problem would probably go a lot of miles for your question, btw.

Comment: You cannot put a specialization within the class definition, and you cannot use `friend` outside the class definition. Declare the template as friend within `Packet` class, specialize it outside, without `friend` keyword.

Answer (score 0):

If I get you correctly, following is what you want to achieve right?

```
 
#include <iostream>
class Packet
{
    public:
    template<class T>
    friend Packet& operator << (Packet& pkt, const T& data);
};

template<class DataType>
Packet& operator << (Packet& pkt, const DataType& data)
{
std::cout << "primary" << std::endl;
return pkt; // handle it as as per your logic
}

template<>
Packet& operator<< (Packet& pkt, const std::string& data)
{
        std::cout << "specialisation for std::string" << std::endl;
        return pkt; // handle it as as per your logic
}

int main()
{
    
    Packet p1;
    p1<<4;
    p1<<std::string("samplestring");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

> How do I make C++ friend template specializations work?

A friend template can declare **only primary templates** and members of primary templates. Any partial specializations and explicit specializations associated with a primary template are **automatically considered friends** too.

So to solve the problem in your code, you can add a *friend template declaration* for the **primary template** inside class `Packet` and then define that primary template as well as any other **specialization** outside the class as shown below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include<string>

struct Packet
{
    //friend template declaration for primary template 
    template<typename DataType>
    friend Packet& operator << (Packet& pkt, const DataType& data);
};

//implementation of primary template
template<typename DataType>
Packet& operator << (Packet& pkt, const DataType& data)
{
      std::cout << "primary template called" << std::endl;
      return pkt;
}
//implementation of explicit specialization
template<>
Packet& operator<<<std::string> (Packet& pkt, const std::string& data)
{
      std::cout << "specialization for std::string called" << std::endl;
      return pkt;
}
int main()
{
    Packet p;
    p << 100; //uses primary template
    
    std::string s("someString");
    p << s; //uses specialization for std::string
    return 0;
}
```

[Working demo](https://onlinegdb.com/B5dCPVEGw).

The changes that i made include:

1. Added a friend template **declaration** for the primary template inside `Packet`.
2. Added implementation for both the primary template as well as explicit specialization outside the class `Packet`. Note that there is no need for the `friend` keyword in the implementation outside class. Moroever, the explicit specialization is automatically a friend of `Packet` so no need to have a friend declaration for this specialization inside the class `Packet`.
3. Added return statement that were missing in the original example question.